# Get list of people having matching skills using sql

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

`I have 2 tables Task and Skill`

## Task table:

| Task_id | skill |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 1 | y |
| 2 | x |
| 2 | z |

## skill :

| agent_name | skills |
| --- | --- |
| abc | x |
| abc | y |
| def | y |
| def | k |
| pqr | x |
| pqr | y |
| abc | z |

I want list of all the agents that can work on a task,
here agent abc and pqr are having all the skills to work on task 1

Comment: Hello, what code have you tried and where is your problem with your try to resolve this ?

Comment: And which one is your real database? There are three of them...

Comment: It is redshift database

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the `agent_name` which have more than the skills needed (but the have the skills needed included ) you should change the on condition:

`on t2.skills_for_task LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.skill_for_task, '%') ;`

```
SELECT agent_name,task_id,skill_for_task
FROM
          (
             select task_id,group_concat(skill) as skill_for_task
             from task
             group by task_id
           ) as t1 
           
           INNER JOIN 
           
           (
             select agent_name,group_concat(skills) as skills_for_task
             from skill
             group by agent_name
           
           ) as t2 
on t2.skills_for_task LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.skill_for_task, '%') ;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=66efe141b29b6d38ddf95e13b8ff1e68

> Result:
>
> ```
> agent_name    task_id skill_for_task
> abc            1            x,y
> pqr            1            x,y
> ```

On `Postgres 13`

```
SELECT agent_name,task_id,skill_for_task
FROM
          (
             select task_id,string_agg(skill,',') as skill_for_task
             from task
             group by task_id
           ) as t1 
           
           INNER JOIN 
           
           (
             select agent_name,string_agg(skills,',') as skills_for_task
             from skill
             group by agent_name
           
           ) as t2 
on t2.skills_for_task LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.skill_for_task, '%') ;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b1df46bb1bf750d7ec0ade979ba9a465

> Result:
>
> ```
> agent_name    task_id skill_for_task
> abc            1            x,y
> pqr            1            x,y
> ```

Comment: In this case if there is a extract skill for an agent then it will not work. For eg if agent pqr is having an extra skill K then it will not work.

Comment: @BiswajeetPraharaj please first check the answer closely then comment if it works or not. The first part of the answer `abc` has an extra skills `z` and it works https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7774b528573bc394b72fe41146ea1ab6

Comment: I tried that and its not working. edited the dataset now and added one more skill to the agent abc. Can you please rerun and let me know the result.

Comment: @BiswajeetPraharaj you have the update version for both MySQL and Postgres